# How to add a string to a remote file with plink

Tags: command-line, ssh, powershell, remote, plink

I'm writing a new backup script in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to back up our [Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/).

After the backup, I need to write into a logfile on a remote Linux server.

I thought about using plink (the [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) command line tool). More or less like this:

```
plink user@server /var/log/logfile<"TEXT"
```

However, most of you will remark that this isn't possible, and I also learned this :)

Is there no easy way to **add a line of text to an existing file on a remote Linux system using plink**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pretty common method is to use `tee`.  Try one of these.

```
echo "TEXT"        | plink.exe user@server tee /var/log/logfile

type localfile.txt | plink.exe user@server tee /var/log/logfile
```

To append the data to the end of the file then use `tee -a`:

```
echo "TEXT"        | plink.exe user@server tee -a /var/log/logfile
 
type localfile.txt | plink.exe user@server tee -a /var/log/logfile
```

Comment: Thx! Actually I should have known this command but I've never used it before.
I did only one small change to make it append the text and not overwrite it everytime:

    echo "TEXT" | plink.exe user@server tee -a /var/log/logfile